# What is the fastest way to convert int64 to byte array?

Tags: go

I want to convert a `int64` to a `[]byte`. I do not care about the encoding. I just care about the performance. Is it possible to do this with a type cast as in C? If I try it, I get:

> cannot convert t (variable of type int64) to type []byte

Comment: Use encoding/binary.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Have to specify the encoding. I want CPU native encoding.

Comment: @ceving, you _have to_ specify the encoding because a value of type `int64` has no implicit endianness on the level of a programming language; this concept only materializes when you're about to serialize or deserialize the value, and you're serializing it (to a series of bytes). You can see how the code suggested [is implemented](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/encoding/binary/binary.go;drc=986b04c0f12efa1c57293f147a9e734ec71f0363;l=84) and do that yourself, if you feel like it: a couple of shifts with truncations.

Comment: Yes, there exists another approach: allocate an int64, type-munge a pointer to it (via `unsafe.Pointer` mess) to produce a pointer to `byte`, then create a slice out of that pointer and do a single assignment to the allocated space, then use the slice. I'm not sure you should do that though. [An example](https://go.dev/play/p/APOinLAovRE)

Comment: that example with the correct number of bytes and the new `unsafe.Slice` function: https://go.dev/play/p/jTkBmMpGx6l

Comment: The **fastest** is `func int642bytesliceFast(i int64) []byte { return nil }`. Won't get faster. Make sure you can live with a non-injective function.

Comment: @volker, This returns empty array.

Comment: @kostix Shifting is exactly what I do **not** want! That is all this question is about. I want the default of the CPU whatever it is.

Comment: «example with the correct number of bytes», oh silly me! Thanks, @JimB :-)

Comment: @XPD: Yes! It's literally _the fastest way_ (which was the only requirement the OP stated). Injective or bijective was not required. Fast. It's always just about fastest.

Comment: Basically all general purpose intel processors are little endien including M1, M2 from Apple. So binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(buffer, value) might be useful.

Comment: If you literally don't care about encoding, then just convert everything to `nil`. It's infinitely fast.

Comment: @XPD PutUint64 always shifts: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/encoding/binary/binary.go;l=107

Comment: Whats the wrong with shift?

Comment: Oh, so you _DO_ care about the encoding.

Comment: That's one meaning of "encoding". But not the only one. There are many lossy encodings in common usage.

Comment: Just for the record–an updated example which does not use `unsafe.Slice`, with correct slice sizing: https://go.dev/play/p/XLiW483_J1j

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JimB for the answer. It works fine.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()
    b := unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&t)), unsafe.Sizeof(t))
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```